# Android Creating Activity with Fragments, onCreateView

Tags: android, android-fragments

I try to understand the way how to create Activities with help of Fragments.
So I programmed an little example to get familiar with this issue.

When running it on my device it will always crash which i don't understand at all.

I know that the problem is caused by onCreatingView(): when I mark it as a comment there won't be an error and onCreate() will be executed.

Can someone explain why the application crashes?

Thanks in advance

---

Here is the relevant snippet of my code

OverviewActivity.java:

```
public class OverviewActivity extends FragmentActivity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_overview);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.overview, menu);
        return true;
    }
}
```

activity_overview:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<fragment
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/overview" 
    android:name="de.jr.dateoverview.OverviewFragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

OverviewFragment.java:

```
public class OverviewFragment extends ListFragment{
    private ListAdapter mAdapter;


    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState){
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
        setEmptyText(getResources().getString(R.string.noEntry));
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        String[] items = new String[] { "Foo", "Bar", "Fizz", "Bin" };

        mAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(), R.layout.overview_tile, R.id.tile1, items);
        setListAdapter(mAdapter);
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView (LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.overview_tile, container, false);
    }
}
```

overview_tile:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TextView 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/tile1" 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:padding="10dip"/>
```

LogCat:

```
03-29 17:47:23.876: D/AndroidRuntime(8773): Shutting down VM
03-29 17:47:23.876: W/dalvikvm(8773): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x415b8ba8)
03-29 17:47:23.876: E/AndroidRuntime(8773): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-29 17:47:23.876: E/AndroidRuntime(8773): Process: de.jr.dateoverview, PID: 8773
03-29 17:47:23.876: E/AndroidRuntime(8773): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{de.jr.dateoverview/de.jr.dateoverview.OverviewActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #1: Error inflating class fragment
03-29 17:47:23.876: E/AndroidRuntime(8773):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2195)
03-29 17:47:23.876: E/AndroidRuntime(8773):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2245)
03-29 17:47:23.876: E/AndroidRuntime(8773):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
03-29 17:47:23.876: E/AndroidRuntime(8773):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
03-29 17:47:23.876: E/AndroidRuntime(8773):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
03-29 17:47:23.876: E/AndroidRuntime(8773):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
03-29 17:47:23.876: E/AndroidRuntime(8773):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
03-29 17:47:23.876: E/AndroidRuntime(8773):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-29 17:47:23.876: E/AndroidRuntime(8773):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
03-29 17:47:23.876: E/AndroidRuntime(8773):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
03-29 17:47:23.876: E/AndroidRuntime(8773):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
03-29 17:47:23.876: E/AndroidRuntime(8773):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
03-29 17:47:23.876: E/AndroidRuntime(8773): Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #1: Error inflating class fragment
03-29 17:47:23.876: E/AndroidRuntime(8773):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:713)
03-29 17:47:23.876: E/AndroidRuntime(8773):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:469)
03-29 17:47:23.876: E/AndroidRuntime(8773):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397)
03-29 17:47:23.876: E/AndroidRuntime(8773):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:353)
03-29 17:47:23.876: E/AndroidRuntime(8773):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:290)
03-29 17:47:23.876: E/AndroidRuntime(8773):     at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1929)
03-29 17:47:23.876: E/AndroidRuntime(8773):     at de.jr.dateoverview.OverviewActivity.onCreate(OverviewActivity.java:16)
03-29 17:47:23.876: E/AndroidRuntime(8773):     at  android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231)
03-29 17:47:23.876: E/AndroidRuntime(8773):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
03-29 17:47:23.876: E/AndroidRuntime(8773):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2159)
03-29 17:47:23.876: E/AndroidRuntime(8773):     ... 11 more
03-29 17:47:23.876: E/AndroidRuntime(8773): Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Your content must have a ListView whose id attribute is 'android.R.id.list'
03-29 17:47:23.876: E/AndroidRuntime(8773):     at android.support.v4.app.ListFragment.ensureList(ListFragment.java:344)
03-29 17:47:23.876: E/AndroidRuntime(8773):     at android.support.v4.app.ListFragment.onViewCreated(ListFragment.java:145)
03-29 17:47:23.876: E/AndroidRuntime(8773):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:906)
03-29 17:47:23.876: E/AndroidRuntime(8773):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1082)
03-29 17:47:23.876: E/AndroidRuntime(8773):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.addFragment(FragmentManager.java:1184)
03-29 17:47:23.876: E/AndroidRuntime(8773):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onCreateView(FragmentActivity.java:291)
03-29 17:47:23.876: E/AndroidRuntime(8773):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:685)
03-29 17:47:23.876: E/AndroidRuntime(8773):     ... 20 more
```

Comment: any error logged in logcat?

Comment: yes, I added it to my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ok so if youre adding that fragment prgrammatically and its already defined in xml, thats youre error. either have it in your container already or add it at runtime, not both

```
03-29 17:47:23.876: E/AndroidRuntime(8773): Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Your content must have a ListView whose id attribute is 'android.R.id.list'
```

and here you need to make sure your id for your llistview is exactly this:'android.R.id.list'

Comment: 03-29 17:47:23.876: E/AndroidRuntime(8773): Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Your content must have a ListView whose id attribute is 'android.R.id.list'

Comment: yes I just wanted to add some more ;)
It's sort of weird. There is a book I'm working with that adds the fragments that way but nevertheless it sounds evident that either dynamically adding or statically "adding" works.
thank you

Answer (score 2):

You can understand error from your logcat output.

```
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Your content must have a ListView whose id attribute is 'android.R.id.list'
```

You are creating ListFragment and you don't have any Listview in your layout.Define listview for your listFragment and set its id as `android.R.id.list`

Answer (score -1):

public class OverviewFragment extends ListFragment{
    private ListAdapter mAdapter;

```
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
    setEmptyText(getResources().getString(R.string.noEntry));
}



@Override
public View onCreateView (LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.overview_tile, container, false); String[] items = new String[] { "Foo", "Bar", "Fizz", "Bin" };

    mAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(), R.layout.overview_tile, R.id.tile1, items);
    setListAdapter(mAdapter);
}


}
```

you only need onCreateView for fragments not onCreate